# Ubuntu Mate 20.04.3, D-Link WLAN

Tags: drivers, wireless, adapter, d-link

How can I activate D-Link DMA-121 WLAN adapter?

---

```
thabo@Thabo-HP-Pavilion:~$ sudo lsusb -t
/:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/4p, 5000M
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/11p, 480M
    |__ Port 3: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
    |__ Port 3: Dev 3, If 1, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
    |__ Port 6: Dev 4, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
    |__ Port 6: Dev 4, If 1, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
    |__ Port 7: Dev 5, If 0, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=btusb, 12M
    |__ Port 7: Dev 5, If 1, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=btusb, 12M
    |__ Port 7: Dev 5, If 2, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=btusb, 12M
    |__ Port 7: Dev 5, If 3, Class=Application Specific Interface, Driver=, 12M
```

Comment: Do you mean DWA-121? Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal command: `lsusb` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Probably you mean DWA-121. It should simply work out the box with *rtl8192cu, rtl8xxxu*  drivers - see https://linux-hardware.org/?probe=d6c16c5786 . Which problems do you actually have? Please add output of `lsusb -t` and `lsmod | grep rtl8` with device connected.